# A homogeneous Poisson process properties proof

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Be $ \left \{ N(t):t \geq 0 \right \}$ a homogeneous Poisson Process with intensity λ.

Show that for arbitrary times $t_{1}< t_{2}<...t_{n}:$

$E[N(t_{n+1})|N(t_{n}),...,N(t_{1})]=N(t_{n})+\lambda (t_{n+1}-t_{n})$

and,is this result valid also in the non-homogeneous context?

I have really tried but I don't know how to approach the problem with the properties, if someone can help me

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look here to check that a Poisson process is a Markov process:

[Show the Markov Property of a Poisson Process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404574/show-the-markov-property-of-a-poisson-process)

Therefore with this at hand, we start with this:

$E[N(t_{n+1})|N(t_{n}),...,N(t_{1})]=E[N(t_{n+1})|N(t_{n})]=$

And now:

$E[N(t_{n+1})|N(t_{n})=n]=$

$=E[N(t_{n+1})-N(t_{n})+N(t_{n})|N(t_{n})=n]=$

$=n+E[N(t_{n+1})-N(t_{n})|N(t_{n})=n]=$

$=n+E[N(t_{n+1})-N(t_{n})|N(t_{n})-N(0)=n]=$

(since $N(0)=0$). Now since the process has independent and Poisson distributed increments, we continue:

$=n+E[N(t_{n+1})-N(t_{n})]=$

$=n+\lambda(t_{n+1}-t_{n})$

This is equivalent to what you wrote.

**UPDATE:** for an inhomogeneous Poisson process:

1- The Markov property remains, since the proof in the link is based on the property of having independent increments, which is true also in the inhomogeneous case ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Interpreted_as_a_counting_process )

2- The calculations above apply directly, but one has to substitute in the last line the integral of the intensity function, leading to:

$E[N(t_{n+1})|N(t_{n}),...,N(t_{1})]=N(t_{n})+\int_{t_n}^{t_{n+1}}\lambda(t) dt$

Comment: Thanks a lot, im read it. And finally, what do you think about the non-homogeneous case, is it valid?

Comment: You are welcome. I will check the definitions that now I do not recall and let you know...

Comment: appreciate it a lot ! thx u

Comment: I wrote what I think happens in the inhomogeneous case ( not an expert so I hope it is correct )